# How to create a txt log file of a "make install"?

Tags: software-installation, log, make

I trying to install a program and I would like to see a txt file with the details of the operation. I think it is called a log file, am I right ?

Once, someone told me to do this command:

```
`make <install> file.txt 2>1 `
```

but it is not working. I need to see the details to know  more about the problems and try to fix them. Please, if someone know how to do it I will be glad to know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I think it should be

`make install >file.txt 2>&1`.

Notice that

1. There is not a left `<`. We are doing output redirection, so nothing to do with brackets.
2. Use `2>&1` instead of `2>1`. `2>1` will redirect `stderr` into a file named `1` instead of `stdout`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
make install > file.txt 2>&1
```